# How to upload and save multiple images in database with laravel 5.4?

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload

im trying to upload multiple images with laravel 5.4, actually the process to upload images is done, the question is how to store them in database?
for example when gonna create a slide show of something that has several images that is uploaded, how to group them so the slide show knows those images are in one group?

can you guys help me?

Comment: ideally you should have a separate folder that shall contain all of your uploaded images. a db should only be used to store their paths. it's simple php to upload an image file to a folder on the system, and it's locator link to the database

Comment: You should save the image path in DB (not the actual image) and load that in the frontend

Comment: If the images are in "groups" you should create a category model. Then define a relationship between the image and category model. That way you can select all the images related to the category. For example a category for birthdays, weddings or landscape.

Comment: of course, the process to upload the image is done. stored them in a folder called 'Images' and saving their path is also done, i mean when we wanted to load them  in front-end, how to they are in the same group?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you go to config/filesystems and turn 'FILESYSTEM_DRIVER' to 'public'

Model to store image paths:

```
class UserDocuments extends Model
{
    //
    protected $table = 'user_documents';

    public function store($user_id, $document_link, $file_name)
    {
        $this->user_id = $user_id;
        $this->document_link = $document_link;
        $this->file_name = $file_name;
        $this->save();
    }
}
```

Code in controller to store files ('document' is file input field name)

```
if ($request->hasFile('document')) {
            $link = $request->file('document')->store('documents');
        }
    $userDocuments->store(request('user_id'), url($link), $link);
```

To show if the images are in a group, you would have to create a database column called 'group_id' and sort them accordingly.

Comment: the code to store the image is working, i think the group_id can solve this. every time, if i want to load the images to the front-end, so i gonna load them by their group_id. thank you.

Answer (score -1):

> We have to store images into one records/row by separting commas.

```
 class DocumentController extends Controller
 {
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
         $pid = $request->input('pid');
         $input = $request->file('files');

         $picture = array();
         if($request->hasFile('files')) : 
            foreach ($images as $item):
              $extension = $item->getClientOriginalName(); //image extension
              $name = time() . '.' .$extension;           //image name
              $item->move('uploads/documents/', $name);  //move to destination
              $arr[] = $name;      //store image into array                   
            endforeach;
            $picture = implode(",", $arr); //Image separated by comma
         else:
            $picture = '';
         endif;

        DB::table('document')->insert(array('pid' => $pid,'image' => $picture));
        Session::flash('message', 'Multiple Images are uploaded successfully');
        return redirect('/multiple-image');
     }
 }
```